# Running Hadoop Wordcount Job Error

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, pom.xml

I am new to using Hadoop, and I am currently trying to run wordcount on a single node cluster on my ubuntu desktop.  I am trying to follow this guide to run the hadoop job:

http://javabeginnerstutorial.com/hadoop/your-first-hadoop-map-reduce-job/

Currently I am stuck on step 3, when I try to `mvn clean install`, this is the error I receive.  I am using the exact same pom.xml file that is linked on step 3.  Was I supposed to edit something in the pom.xml file in order to successfully compile? Or do the links possibly not work?  Any help would be great. Thanks.

```
hduser@venus:~/development/Hadoop_projects/word_count$ mvn clean install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.impetus.code:hadoop-examples:jar:1.0
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin is missing. @ line 38, column 12
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING] 
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building hadoop-examples 1.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ hadoop-examples ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.3:resources (default-resources) @ hadoop-examples ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/hduser/development/Hadoop_projects/word_count/src/main/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.0.2:compile (default-compile) @ hadoop-examples ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.3:testResources (default-testResources) @ hadoop-examples ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/hduser/development/Hadoop_projects/word_count/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.0.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ hadoop-examples ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.10:test (default-test) @ hadoop-examples ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO] Surefire report directory: /home/hduser/development/Hadoop_projects/word_count/target/surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.874s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Jul 15 00:34:04 PDT 2015
[INFO] Final Memory: 7M/240M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.10:test (default-test) on project hadoop-examples: Error creating properties files for forking; nested exception is java.io.IOException: No such file or directory -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Comment: I have no idea what the pom.xml file should be doing, any input on POM would be helpful.

Comment: The `pom.xml` tells maven what do: download files, build artifacts (jars / classes) and the like. It seems pretty clear that maven is failing when trying to do something with the surefire plugin. What exactly is happening will require looking at the contents of pom.xml.

Comment: I still cannot get this to compile.  I don't see anything in the pom regarding surfire plugin. I am using this pom.xml: https://github.com/xamry/hadoop-examples/blob/master/pom.xml

Answer (score 0):

Try to get the pom and maven dependice from this http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core
Try to check the hadoop version before adding this pom file.

Answer (score 0):

Run the maven command with -DskipTests

Comment: I still get a build failure, but it seems that worked to go around the surefire-plugin issue.  the error i receive now is: [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:2.2:jar (default-jar) on project WordCount: Error assembling JAR: Failed to create directory: /home/hduser/development/Hadoop_projects/word_count/target/maven-archiver -> [Help 1]